# How can I replace characters in LEET style?

Tags: java

actually i am beginner in java

I want to know how to write a program that prints string after replacing some letters.

For example,

> I love = 1 L0v3
>
> Winter is coming = W1nt3r 1s c0m1ng

I want to replace:

- `A` with `4`,
- `E` with `3`,
- `I` with `1`,
- and `O` with `0`.

I've stucked with that code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scaneer sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string :");
        String original = sc.readLine();
        String replaced = "stuff";
        System.out.printlb(original + " = " + replaced);
    }
}
```

Comment: what language? get this out of js if it ain't js.

Comment: There should be a replace method to do that. Not a Java coder. Also java != javascript

Comment: Some users suggest a solution with `String#replaceAll()`. It works but you will iterate on the String once per character to replace. I suggest you to loop on the array (use `String.toCharArray()`) and build a new String with `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

There's the method [String.replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that does exactly what you want.

Example usage:

```
String word = "Winter";
word = word.replaceAll("i","1");
System.out.println(word); //Outputs 'W1nter'.
```

Keep in mind that this is case-sensitive (so replacing a doesn't replace A).

Things could be made more efficient by using better regular expressions and caching the regular expression too, but I won't go deep into that as you're a beginner. Feel free to google "java cache regex".

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all the characters, ignoring uppercase and lowercase. The `(?i)` is regex for case insensitivity.

```
String convertMe = "winter is coming";

convertMe = convertMe.replaceAll("(?i)a", "4")
            .replaceAll("(?i)e", "3")
            .replaceAll("(?i)i", "1")
            .replaceAll("(?i)o", "0");

System.out.println(convertMe); //Prints: w1nt3r 1s c0m1ng
```

Answer (score 1):

Some users suggest a solution with `String#replaceAll()`. It works but you will iterate on the String once per character to replace.

I suggest you to loop on the array (use `String.toCharArray()`) and build a new String using `StringBuilder`.

```
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>(); // <-- Store the mapping into a map;
map.put('3','e');
map.put('4','a');
...

//Then, create a StringBuilder. It allows you to build a String...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//Then loop on your String : 
for(char c :  yourString.toCharArray()) {
  if(map.containsKey(c)) {
    sb.append(map.get(c));
  } else {
    sb.append(c);
  }
}

System.out.println("the result is "+sb.toString());
```

Comment: I like your solution, but you can modify it to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should be encoding the replacements as chars, not ints, because you are going to be replacing them in a *string*. As an example:

```
System.out.println("Hello".replace('e', '3')); // Will print "H3llo"
```

Notice how the `'3'` is a char, not an int. You would then do this for all values you would like to replace.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8 or later:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>() {{
            put('A', '4');
            put('E', '3');
            put('I', '1');
            put('O', '0');
        }};
        String original = "WINTER IS COMING";
        String replaced = map.entrySet().stream().reduce(original, (acc, e) -> acc.replace(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
        System.out.println(replaced); // W1NT3R 1S C0M1NG
    }
}
```